# Cant find csx file

Tags: unity-game-engine, types, visual-studio-code, omnisharp

> [INFORMATION:OmniSharp.ScriptCs.ScriptCsProjectSystem] Could not find
>   any CSX files

I recently started using VS code with the Unity plugin. Everything worked fine until things got ugly. For what ever reason inteli-sense partially stopped working and my types are no longer color coded. I thought this was a theme issue but when i opened the project in monoDev the issue was there as well.

I tried creating a new project and opening it in monoDev. Works fine. The moment i install the VS code plugin the issue comes back.

Comment: Which unity plugin are you using? This is likely a bug in the plugin and we should open an issue in the plugin's repo.

Comment: https://github.com/dotBunny/VSCode